# Select values per hour and highlight max value in separate column

Tags: mysql

I am running the following query..

```
select date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as hour
     , current_value
     , "null" as null_value
  from History_Data 
 where (timestamp >= (now() - interval 24 hour)) 
    and metric_id = '4'
  group by hour  
  order by hour desc
  limit 24
```

and its returning..

```
 hour   current_value   null_value
 2014-04-16 23:00:00    41449   null
 2014-04-16 22:00:00    117462  null
 2014-04-16 21:00:00    103954  null
 2014-04-16 20:00:00    39421   null
 2014-04-16 19:00:00    17269   null
 2014-04-16 18:00:00    14950   null
 2014-04-16 17:00:00    13813   null
 2014-04-16 16:00:00    13246   null
 2014-04-16 15:00:00    12882   null
 2014-04-16 14:00:00    13512   null
 2014-04-16 13:00:00    13228   null
 2014-04-16 12:00:00    12850   null
 2014-04-16 11:00:00    12918   null
 2014-04-16 10:00:00    11923   null
 2014-04-16 09:00:00    11480   null
 2014-04-16 08:00:00    10890   null
 2014-04-16 07:00:00    10285   null
 2014-04-16 06:00:00    10350   null
 2014-04-16 05:00:00    10151   null
 2014-04-16 04:00:00    10917   null
 2014-04-16 03:00:00    12714   null
 2014-04-16 02:00:00    14758   null
 2014-04-16 01:00:00    18018   null
 2014-04-16 00:00:00    21584   null
```

I'm nearly there..  What I would like is to highlight the max value..  So the output should look something like..

```
 hour            current_value  null_value
 2014-04-16 23:00:00    41449   null
 2014-04-16 22:00:00    117462  null
 **2014-04-16 21:00:00  103954  "103954 21:00"**
 2014-04-16 20:00:00    39421   null
 2014-04-16 19:00:00    17269   null
 2014-04-16 18:00:00    14950   null
 2014-04-16 17:00:00    13813   null
 2014-04-16 16:00:00    13246   null
 2014-04-16 15:00:00    12882   null
 2014-04-16 14:00:00    13512   null
 2014-04-16 13:00:00    13228   null
 2014-04-16 12:00:00    12850   null
 2014-04-16 11:00:00    12918   null
 2014-04-16 10:00:00    11923   null
 2014-04-16 09:00:00    11480   null
 2014-04-16 08:00:00    10890   null
 2014-04-16 07:00:00    10285   null
 2014-04-16 06:00:00    10350   null
 2014-04-16 05:00:00    10151   null
 2014-04-16 04:00:00    10917   null
 2014-04-16 03:00:00    12714   null
 2014-04-16 02:00:00    14758   null
 2014-04-16 01:00:00    18018   null
 2014-04-16 00:00:00    21584   null
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect there are some other issues in the query you posted, but that may be because you tried to simplify for the question. Ignoring anything else, I believe you can accomplish your goal by adding a CASE with a SUBQUERY. Mine below is an example, you can make the output anything you want.

```
select date_format(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') as hour
     , current_value
     , CASE WHEN current_value = (SELECT MAX(current_value) 
                                    FROM History_Data 
                                   WHERE (timestamp >= (NOW() - interval 24 hour)) 
                                     AND metric_id = '4') 
            THEN 'I AM MAX' ELSE NULL 
        END null_value
  from History_Data 
 where (timestamp >= (now() - interval 24 hour)) 
    and metric_id = '4'
  group by hour  
  order by hour desc
  limit 24
```

I don't trust the use of current_value since it is neither an aggregate not in the group by clause. In SQL Server that would error, but in MySQL it is instead returning a value. I suspect it is by default acting as an ANY(current_value) and that may be why you don't see the result you want.

You might fix it by replacing:

```
     , MAX(current_value)
     , CASE WHEN MAX(current_value) = (SELECT MAX(current_value) 
                                    FROM History_Data 
                                   WHERE (timestamp >= (NOW() - interval 24 hour)) 
                                     AND metric_id = '4') 
            THEN 'I AM MAX' ELSE NULL 
        END null_value
```

with

```
     , current_value
     , CASE WHEN current_value = (SELECT MAX(current_value) 
                                    FROM History_Data 
                                   WHERE (timestamp >= (NOW() - interval 24 hour)) 
                                     AND metric_id = '4') 
            THEN 'I AM MAX' ELSE NULL 
        END null_value
```

I made a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/777a2/8/0) showing a similar structure with a vastly simplified use case. It demonstrate both the "any " problem and my proposed solution.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT, val INT);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(3,1); 

SELECT id
      ,val --
      ,CASE WHEN val = (SELECT MAX(val) FROM tbl) 
            THEN 'I AM MAX' ELSE NULL 
        END ValIsMax
      ,CASE WHEN MAX(val) = (SELECT MAX(val) FROM tbl) 
            THEN 'I AM MAX' ELSE NULL 
        END GroupMaxValIsMax
      ,MAX(val)
  FROM tbl
 GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Many Thanks for this..  I tried it but it still gives null's for all the hours..  I trimmed the output so it would fit                  2014-04-19 20:00:00 63714 NULL
2014-04-19 19:00:00 112438 NULL
2014-04-19 18:00:00 93196 NULL
2014-04-19 17:00:00 40210 NULL
2014-04-19 16:00:00 34322 NULL
2014-04-19 15:00:00 32488 NULL
2014-04-19 14:00:00 36808 NULL
2014-04-19 13:00:00 34720 NULL
2014-04-19 12:00:00 31495 NULL
2014-04-19 11:00:00 26759 NULL
2014-04-19 10:00:00 19000 NULL

Comment: I think that is the result of other issues. I've update my answer to try to help further.

Comment: Thank you very much..  That seemed to have done the trick..  , MAX(current_value)
     , CASE WHEN MAX(current_value) = (SELECT MAX(current_value) 
                                    FROM History_Data 
                                   WHERE (timestamp >= (NOW() - interval 24 hour)) 
                                     AND metric_id = '4') 
            THEN 'I AM MAX' ELSE NULL 
        END null_value

Comment: You are welcome. You can up vote the answer as useful and accept to show that your question has been answered.